# Can't find method with @selector - NSInvalidArgumentException since iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

after updating to iOS8 and compiling my app with XCode6, I get a very strange exception when clicking on a button.

My button is defined like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(cellButtonPressed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

In "@selector" I defined the method which is called when button is pressed:

```
-(void) cellButtonPressed:(id)sender {    
    NSLog(@"Hello again");
}
```

I also added this method to my header file .h

This button is placed into a `UITableViewCell` as a subview:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 54, cell.frame.origin.y+20, 36, 36);

[cell addSubview:button];
```

This worked very fine on iOS7. But now, on iOS8, I get an exception after clicking on the button:

```
2014-09-25 08:33:47.461 ****[12442:1669165] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewWrapperView type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ce35560'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185dae084 0x1963940e4 0x185db5094 0x185db1e48 0x185cb708c 0x10005a928 0x18a5652f4 0x18a54e44c 0x18a56dff8 0x18a524724 0x18a55e7b8 0x18a55de58 0x18a531660 0x18a7cfd6c 0x18a52fbc8 0x185d66324 0x185d655c8 0x185d63678 0x185c91664 0x18edd35a4 0x18a596984 0x10004b324 0x196a02a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does anybody know why?

Thx for you help!

Comment: Do you have any UIGestureRecognizer somewhere?

Comment: problem in here [UITableViewWrapperView type] check the condition of this method

Comment: nope, no UIGestureRecognizer...but: button is placed into a UITableViewCell as subview (added this information to question). Could this be the problem?

Comment: can you post the whole code for `cellForTableView:atIndexPath` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer because of an advice in comments:

The method in selector is called properly. Problem exists in getting cell from superview.

On iOS7 I get the clicked button within cell with following code:

```
UserTableViewCell *cell = (UserTableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
```

Now, on iOS8, I have to get the cell with this call:

```
UserTableViewCell *cell = (UserTableViewCell *)[sender superview];
```

So, this is a solution for me:

```
-(void)cellButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    UserTableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 8) {
        cell = (UserTableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    } else {
        cell = (UserTableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    }

    // do your stuff
}
```

So, view stack of TableViewCell seems to be another. Good to know :)

Thanks guys!